# Texture paint changing the whole texture

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

The texture poaint mode is behaving really weird for me. Im trying to draw on to my wall but its changing the texture of the whole model.
After hitting tab it's going back to normal tho.

GIF:
[image]

EDIT: when i click use nodes this happens:
 [image]

Comment: Go into the node editor for the material applied to the mesh and select the right image texture node.

Comment: @HATMAN makes even more weird things happen (check the edit)

Comment: Ah this is the Internal render engine, I am more of a Cycles whiz. I haven't texture painted in the Internal engine before, so I have not had to deal with this issue in it. I added a tag so people know right off the bat in future

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the internal renderer either, but this is just a model for a game engine... and i didn't bother switching.

Comment: If you check `Use Nodes` you should select which material it's linked to in the Node Editor window (drop-down list in the Material node). However I'm not sure what nodes are needed in this case for, as originally the problem was with texture painting. Check if texture is repeated over mesh (tiled), and if it is you'll need to find a way to not affect original texture when drawing (so to draw sort of on another layer)